# Basic error in trying inserting data in a DataBase with ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to learn how to use ASP. In one of my first pages i wrote this in trying to add a form data into a database:

```vb
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Itinerary"
Set RS = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" ) 
RS.ActiveConnection = Con
RS.lockType= 3
RS.Open sqlString
RS.AddNew
RS("title") = title
RS("subtitle") = subtitle
RS.Update
RS.Close
```

but I get the following error in the third line of the code

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict
with one another.
```

Anyone has any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: What does `title` and `subtitle` variables contain? Does the `RS("title")` and `RS("subtitle")` column values exist in your `Itinerary` table? Just to be clear this approach is not the best consider using `INSERT INTO Itinerary (title, subtitle) VALUES (?, ?)` and the `ADODB.Command` object.

Comment: If you're getting an issue with the third line of code, can you show us your connection string, please (obviously without the username and password).

Comment: @Paul Problem is we don't know where the problem lies, the error has been posted but no suggestion to which line is causing it and to be honest the OP probably doesn't know if they haven't got detailed errors being sent by the server.

Answer (score -1):

What are you doing exactly with the following code? It looks like you are reading and writing at the same time?  If you are trying to read what is in the DB (my guess because you have a select query) then you need to drop the

AddNew, Update from your code. 
Should look more like this

```
sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Itinerary"
Set RS = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" ) 
RS.ActiveConnection = Con
RS.lockType= 3
RS.Open sqlString

vtitle = RS("title") 'store title to variable
vsubtitle = RS("subtitle") 'store subtitle to variable

RS.Close

Response.Write(vtitle & " - Title")
```

Comment: actually I need to write on the DB. I've found this way to do it and i've tried it. But it's not the proper way I guess.

Comment: The OP is using ADODB to add a new record into the `Itinerary` table, you've changed what was an insert new record into a retrieve an existing record??

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```vb
Function AddNewData(title, subtitle)
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" ) 
    rs.Open "Itinerary",Con, adopenstatic, adlockoptimistic, adcmdtable
    rs.AddNew
    rs("title") = title
    rs("subtitle") = subtitle
    rs.Update
    rs.close
    Set rs=nothing
End Function
```

Comment: No explanation of usage for the OP just try this? Why is it a `Function` it's not returning anything is it, it could have quite easily been a `Sub` procedure.

Comment: Also how is that any different? - *"Oh OP has an issue I know let's wrap it in a function that will make it work"*!

Comment: Please note different open command parameters - seems pretty evident if you read the code.

Comment: Please note changing the command parameters or wrapping it in a function will not solve a `Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.` error. Regardless *"try this :"* is just lazy. Here's an idea actually *attempt* to explain why putting the code in a function and changing the command parameters will fix the error.

Comment: I wrote a solution, that's more than you did so I fail to see how you can refer to someone else as lazy.  Lazy is sitting back and critiquing other people's work.  I believe offering the correct arguments does resolve the problem. Wrapping it in a function is how I write code. If you don't like it, unwrap it. If you have a better solution, provide it. Otherwise, find a better way to use your time, besides complaining. In any case let the OP be the judge.

Comment: It's simple this question has been asked to death and there are plenty of poor answers like yours. Why leave an answer in a hope of bagging some cheap rep? Instead don't leave an answer (especially when it's wrong) and encourage the OP to search for the answer. Leaving an answer just adds to the problem.

Comment: Actually, the only problem so far is you, and you still bring nothing to the table.